# C# alternative to (Application.OpenForms[0] as Form1)

Tags: c#, forms

is there a better alternative to the following code When calling a method in an already open form?

```
(Application.OpenForms[0] as Form1).someMethod();
```

That line of code is of course being executed in a class.

to make it more clear here is an example:

Form Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void someMethod()
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```

Class Code:

```
class Class1
{
    public void aMethod()
    {
        (Application.OpenForms[0] as Form1).someMethod();
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to call someMethod?

Comment: The best alternative is to not call methods on other forms directly. You're tightly binding your classes and forms. My suggestion is to use a custom event. Create an event in the class. Have your forms subscribe to the class's event, and when the event is triggered, the handler in the class can call the method for you. That way, your `Class1` doesn't have to know anything at all about `Form1`.

Comment: That actually makes sense, I guess my way is just a quick dirty fix.

Comment: You reap what you sow. Stop being dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Class1 instance doesn't already have a reference to the Form1 instance then there is not other way.  That begs a couple of questions though.

Firstly, if that Class1 object needs to directly affect that Form1 instance then why doesn't it already have that reference?  Where did that Class1 object come from?  Most likely the Form1 instance created it.  If so, why didn't Form1 pass a reference to itself into the Class1 object when it was created?

Secondly, why is that Class1 object directly affecting the Form1 instance anyway?  Most likely a better design would be for the Class1 object to raise an event that Form1 can handle and then affect itself.

Comment: This might sound stupid but, how do I get "Form1 to pass a reference to itself into the Class1 object"?

Comment: So, if Form1 is creating the Class1 instance, it's as easy as giving the Class1's constructor a Form1 parameter. Then, when instantiating it, you would do this: `Class1 myInstance = new Class1(this);` (from the form, of course). Still, events are better.

Comment: Class1 has to be written with the expectation that it will receive that reference, so you must add an appropriate constructor, method or property, just as you always do when you want to pass data into an object.  It's no different to any other data so don;t try to think of it any differently and make something hard when it's not.  Just as is always the case, a Form1 instance refers to itself using the 'this' keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just provide `Class1` with the instance of the form.

Comment: And using a ctor with `this` won't?