# Call a usercontrol’s method from a form c#?

Tags: c#, forms, methods, dynamic-usercontrols

I have the method listviewupdate() in usercontrol schuler.
Usercontrol schuler is in form1.
Then I have form2. When I click a button in form2 I want to call the method listviewupdate().

I tried creating a second method in form1 which calls the listviewupdate() method, and then calling this second method in form 2 but I get an error.
Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

In your file `Program.cs`, you can define a globally accessible variable:

```
static class Program
{
    //  for external access to Form1 methods
    public static Form1 MainForm;

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        MainForm = new Form1(args);
        Application.Run(MainForm);
    }
}
```

The static variable `MainForm` can then be used to access any public method to `Form1` via `Program.MainForm.MyMethod()`.

Assuming, you have access to the `Form2` object from within `Form1`, you can use the `Form2` object variable to call `Form2` methods out of `Form1` methods.

Be aware that you might run into problems when (unknowingly ...) using more than one thread. Read about [BeginInvoke](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10311/What-s-up-with-BeginInvoke).

Answer (score 0):

@Axel Kemper thanks for the response. I did how you told me with `Program.MainForm.MyMethod()` but it didn't find MyMethod().
Then I went in the form1.Designer and there I saw that the usercontrol was set to private, also I switched it to public and now it works with `Program.MainForm.schuler1.MyMethod() //schuler1 is the name of my user control`.

I just don't understand why it doesn't work with

`Form1 form1 = Application.OpenForms[1] as Form1;
 form1.schuler1.ListviewUpdate(); //schuler1 is the name of my usercontrol`

even if the user control is set to public I get the error "System.NullReferenceException" in `main.schuler1.ListviewUpdate();`

Comment: Use `Application.OpenForms[0]` to get the first form as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21564542/1911064).